# Seperating text file output into two vectors

Tags: r

So I have the output

```
"[(9.010658025741577, 2.8047988414764404), (9.242822885513306, 2.66866397857666), (9.263759851455688, 2.6707050800323486), (9.515105962753296, 2.5500648021698)]"
```

I use the command:

```
read_txt_file <- scan("my_file.txt", what="", sep="\n")
```

Now i want to separate the output into two vectors, so that it would be:

```
x = "[9.010658025741577, 9.242822885513306, 9.263759851455688, 9.515105962753296]"
```

and

```
y= "[ 2.8047988414764404, 2.66866397857666, 2.6707050800323486), 2.5500648021698)]"
```

Any idead how to do this easily? Thanks.

Comment: What is the condition, why this way? so we could generalize it.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, the condition is to extract odd and even number to separate vectors. Also the output could be of any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `x` is a concatenation of each first coordinate of the vector and `y` of the second.

Assuming you have output like this.

```
output <- "[(9.010658025741577, 2.8047988414764404), (9.242822885513306, 2.66866397857666), (9.263759851455688, 2.6707050800323486), (9.515105962753296, 2.5500648021698)]"
```

You can do the following.

```
clean_output <- gsub("\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)", "", output) # remove brackets and parenthesis
coord_mat <- matrix(unlist(strsplit(clean_output, ", ")),ncol = 2, byrow = T)
# retrieve coordinates as a matrix arranged the way you like
x <- paste0("[", paste(coord_mat[,1], collapse = ", "), "]")
y <- paste0("[", paste(coord_mat[,2], collapse = ", "), "]")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
text1 <- "[(9.010658025741577, 2.8047988414764404), (9.242822885513306, 2.66866397857666), (9.263759851455688, 2.6707050800323486), (9.515105962753296, 2.5500648021698)]"


x <- paste0("[",paste0(c(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[^0-9\\.\\,]", "", text1), ",")))[seq(1,7,2)], collapse = ", "), "]")
y <- paste0("[",paste0(c(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[^0-9\\.\\,]", "", text1), ",")))[seq(2,8,2)], collapse = ", "), "]")


> x
[1] "[9.010658025741577, 9.242822885513306, 9.263759851455688, 9.515105962753296]"
> y
[1] "[2.8047988414764404, 2.66866397857666, 2.6707050800323486, 2.5500648021698]"
```

With the gsub command you only keep the digits, decimal points and commas. Subsequently, you split the string into substrings with the comma as the separator. Then you unlist these substrings and put them in a vector. For x you keep the uneven elements, and for y the even elements. Next, you paste all elements in x (and also for y) together by setting collapse = "," in the paste0 command. Finally, you paste0 a "[" at the beginning and a "]" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
#Loading text
text <- "[(9.010658025741577, 2.8047988414764404), (9.242822885513306, 2.66866397857666), (9.263759851455688, 2.6707050800323486), (9.515105962753296, 2.5500648021698)]"

#Extracting the numbers from the string and creating a tbl_df
text <- text %>% 
  stringr::str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>%
  unlist() %>% 
  as.numeric() %>% 
  tbl_df()

#Creating new tbl_df for odd and even 
EvenNumbers <- text[floor(text$value) %% 2 == 0, ] 
OddNumbers <- text[floor(text$value) %% 2 == 1, ]
```